# ng-view html showing as plain string. how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, haml

ng-view html showing as plain string. how can I fix it?

Error screenshot.
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s179/sh/b7cf9275-7d18-4b5d-8599-a4b7ec5c3bbc/c9ec67b08744057a3a78ab4f20dd97aa

Sorry, i can not upload images.

Comment: seems to me the problem is not in Angular, it looks like something not rendered right. may be something wrong with your `haml` ?

Comment: joining the above, show code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use ng-view to load jade/haml?  You'll need to have that compile to html before angular will be able to use it as a view.

Comment: At least give him some working examples if you're posting it as an answer

Comment: Yes. The problem was in haml. I used the html, and the problem was solved. Thank you all.